# Prevent kiosk mode webview link from opening new tab

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app, kiosk, google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode

I've created a chrome app that opens in kiosk mode, inside my chrome app i have a webview which is similar to an iframe except it works for chrome apps. On the website inside the webview there is a link that tries to open in a new tab, and fails.. At the moment it just does nothing when the button is clicked.

Is there a way to make all links inside the webview not open in new tabs? Or is there any other work around that you can think of?

I firebugged the link and this is what it says (i was expecting _blank but..):

```
<a class="js-tablink" href="/foh" target="FOH">

                 //link stuff
</a>
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-newwindow

Comment: I donf really understand what that is telling me if im honest

Comment: the website that inside my webview is trying to open a new tab, not window.

Comment: where do i put this in my js? Do i need to add anything to it?